# How to change a Button's background after click?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have to change my button's background after click. Here is my XAML Code:

```
<Style x:Key="BackColor"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="SEND"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF06C548"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Global User Interface"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="17" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                            Height="63"
                            Margin="192,17,177,10"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0EAC44"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property ="ClickMode" Value="Release">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1B74CB"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

When I start my program, the Button doesn't work, but the color that I need is set. **What I need to change to make my Button working correctly?** I would be so happy, if I get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an animation and set the fillbehavior to holdend.
Maybe it isn't red you want but:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                       <ColorAnimation To="Red" 
                                       Duration="0" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                       FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                       />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like code behind but here's a solution:

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="Button1"
        Click="Button1_Click"
        Background="Red"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Control control) control.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

I would much rather show you this with binding instead but it's a little more code to setup properly.